# Android - Proguard didn't compile with Joda Time jar file

Tags: android, apk, proguard, jodatime

I used Joda time API in my android project, my project didn't compile when i export a signed apk, it showing the error "Proguard returned with error code 1. See console", below is the error log,

```
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.DateMidnight: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.DateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.DateTimeZone: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Days: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Duration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Hours: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Instant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.LocalDate: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.LocalTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Minutes: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.MonthDay: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Months: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.MutableDateTime: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.MutablePeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Period: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Seconds: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.YearMonth: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.Years: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.base.AbstractDuration: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: org.joda.time.base.AbstractPeriod: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.ToString
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] Warning: there were 37 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-07-20 00:50:25 - CC]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

my proguard.cfg file looks like,

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

can anyone help me on this? i need to publish my app.
the solution will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the post here: https://plus.google.com/112998433182673852267/posts/ApBBBjv9szw

> What is actually happening is that the missing "FromString" class is an annotation that is not actually present as a class file in joda-time-2.0.jar. There's a claim (http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10575) that a missing annotation class file is not supposed to affect compilation, which sounds correct, but I don't know where this is formally stated.

You'll need to add http://joda-convert.sourceforge.net/ to your project's build path.

Comment: Hi @Morrison Chang, i added that joda-convert-1.3.1 jar file, still this problem exists. now the warnings reduced by 31. can you help me on this?

Comment: @Amarnath If is a different problem (warning/error), you are better off with a different question. Otherwise update your question.

Comment: Hi @Morrison Chang, i added that final error log below as a answer. can you help me on this also?

Comment: You should add it as part of your question. Also you are exporting both joda-time and joda-convert?

Comment: it showing error in DateTime class when i remove that joda-time jar

Comment: You should have both. How are you doing to your builds with proguard (eclipse/ant/maven)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33806/discussion-between-morrison-chang-and-amarnath)

Answer (score 54):

If the missing classes aren't needed, you can suppress the warnings:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)

Comment: hi @Eric Lafortune, where should i use the above code. project.properties or proguard.cfg?

Comment: Hi @Eric Lafortune, now i can able to build. but it showing error in actionbar sherlock while running the app.

Comment: Hi now i can build and run the prj successfully. thanks for your support. i added the actionbar sherlock suport codes in my proguard file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for this question. Two thumbs up for this short and sweet post, @EricLafortune .

Comment: Where do I add the `dontwarn` line?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by adding the following to my build.gradle > dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.joda', name: 'joda-convert', version: '2.0.1', classifier: 'classic'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```